# Multiple pattern test in the definition of a function

Tags: argument-patterns

I have a very simple question, and I'm sure there is a way to do this but I cannot find it:

if I want to create a function that's defined only for matrices, I can do it like this:

```
f[x_?MatrixQ]:=Det[x];
```

but what if I want to define a function which is defined only for matrices whose entries are numbers? I would like to combine MatrixQ with NumberQ for its matrix elements but I'm not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was going for a syntactic pattern thing, but actually the two-argument form of `MatrixQ` should work here:

```
f[x_?(MatrixQ[#,NumberQ]&)]
```

> MatrixQ[expr,test]
>   gives True only if test yields True when applied to each of the matrix elements in expr.

Comment: I had tried something like this, but without the parenthesis. This works, thanks!